# tramp and sudo: how to edit files under another account

Tags: tramp

On local machine, I am using the account as test1, and I could use the same account to login remote server. After login as test1 on remote server, I could run `sudo su - oracle` to change as oracle user, and then I could all files under account of oracle. But I don't know the password of oracle, I could only change to oracle using `sudo su - oracle`. So how to use tramp to edit the file from oracle account on remote server? I read the tramp document, it said we have sudo and su option. I can't simple use su since I don't have the password of oracle. But if using sudo, looks like it doesn't work as the emacs hangs forever.

Answer (score 11):

To ssh in as you, and then run sudo su oracle, and then edit a file, do this:

```
/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:oracle@remotehost:/path/to/file
```

Comment: Please make it self standing (i.e. readable without having seen @phils's answer)

Comment: What @Stefan said. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: This appears to work (prompts for password) but after entering the password, autocomplete for the remote path stops working, and it keeps prompting for the password as I type a filepath. If I manually type the whole filepath, it asks if I want to create a directory (which should already exist) so I suspect it's the wrong location somehow.  Using Emacs 26.3, spacemacs 0.200.13, tramp 2.3.5.26.3.  `password-cache` is set to `t`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It will prompt for your password to ssh to remotehost.  Then it will prompt for your password again to do the sudo su oracle.  Depending on what fancy spacemacs autocomplete stuff is going on, you might see some weirdness.  I use ido and sometimes when doing complicated tramp stuff like this I have to hit c-f to exit ido and get plain-vanilla emacs behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a (cross-site) duplicate, as the question has a fairly comprehensive answer on Stack Overflow:

[Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177687/324105)

> But if using sudo, looks like it doesn't work as the emacs hangs forever.

As you neither show what you've tried, nor provide any details on how far tramp gets (customize the `tramp-verbose` option), it's extremely difficult to tell whether there's still a problem, or what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su - oracle` is not supported by Tramp out-of-the-box. You would need to define an own method in `tramp-methods` for this, kind of tricky.

I fear it will be to detailed to fiddle it out here on stackexchange. You might rather ask on the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` mailing list.

Comment: I think they're actually just looking for `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:oracle@remotehost:/path/to/file`