# Tramp su seems to not work

Tags: tramp, ssh

I would like to upgrade my current workflow so I can use Emacs to edit a file on a remote machine. Here is what I have to do now:

```
ssh remote # password1 required
sudo su -l otheruser # password2 required
```

I should note that `remote` is defined in my `~/.ssh/config` file and I am using a password to protect my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key.

But (a) I don't know the exact syntax for this command and (b) what I have tried seems to not work.

Here is my first attempt, based on [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/tramp-and-sudo-how-to-edit-files-under-another-account) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs):

```
C-x C-f /sshx:remote|su:otheruser@remote:
```

This prompts me first for the password for `remote`, and then prompts for the password for `otheruser@remote`. And then nothing - no error message, but also no remote file access.

Is this syntax correct to recreate the basic "first ssh, then su" workflow from above?

Comment: The TRAMP path looks correct -  I just tested the same on Linux with Emacs 27.0.91.  Worked correctly.  Have you tried setting `tramp-verbose` to 3 or higher, then looking in the `*Messages*` buffer after?

Comment: n.b. Tramp debug messages go to a buffer named `*debug tramp/FOO*` for the connection FOO.

Comment: I think the root cause was not being on the right VPN for the initial host, although on second thought that doesn't make sense because using plain ssh from a terminal worked. In trying to fix this, I got my emacs into a bad state with recently opened files asking for passwords and not allowing my config file to load properly. At this point I think there's too much other noise going on in my setup for this question to be properly answered.